# Qt fails to open shell32.lib even when included

Tags: qt

I have a QT 5.4 project compiling with MSVC2013 64 bit that throws the linker error 
LNK1104: cannot open file 'shell32.lib'. Every Qt Widgets app on Windows requires this library.

This error is thrown regardless of whether a path to that lib is specified, and
if I include some other library, I get no error for that library, which leads me to believe that the Qt Creator is automatically looking for shell32 in a location specified somewhere other than the .pro file.

The .pro file looks like this.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += $$quote(C:/Program Files             (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Lib/shell32.lib)
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += $$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Lib/shell32.lib)

INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft   SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Include)
DEPENDPATH += $$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Include)
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but shell32.lib is one of the libraries listed under the QMAKE_LIBS_CORE variable in qmake.conf.

**SOLUTION**

In the Projects tab on the left pane, add the desired library paths to the LIB variable, and add the path to SC.exe (also in the Windows SDK) to the PATH variable. The latter is necessary or else you get "LNK 1158: can't execute rc.exe."
Apparently the LIBS += statement in my .pro doesn't work, although INCLUDEPATH +=  does (I get "can't find windows.h" when it's removed).

I don't know why the LIBS+= doesn't work or why I also need the path to RC.exe (I never had to add it using Visual Studio), but at least there is a solution.

Comment: I think the first step would be for you to show us what your .pro file looks like and you should also be able to find the link line in the compile output and post that as well.

Comment: done. 
The only compiler output is the elapsed time, and the only linker output is ":-error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'shell32.lib' "
There are also the following warnings:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\sal_supp.h:57: warning: C4005: '__useHeader' : macro redefinition"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\specstrings_supp.h:77: warning: C4005: '__on_failure' : macro redefinition

Comment: Are there really all those extra spaces in the directory names?

Comment: no it just came out that way when I copy/pasted it here

Comment: Found a solution, will put in original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. Open the Projects tab on the left pane, and:

1. Add all desired library paths to the LIB variable
2. Add the path for sc.exe (in the Windows SDK/bin folder) to PATH
3. Rebuild.

So apparently putting LIBS += in the .pro file just doesn't work in my Qt, although INCLUDEPATH+= for headers does. Oh well.

Comment: I was under the impression that LIBS += made it unnecessary to set an environment variable. Apparently not. Qt noob mistake.

Comment: Also make sure you always run qmake after making changes when you are using VC++ compiler in QMake (as mentioned below by Midhun)

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me (Win7 x64, Visual Studio 2013.5, Qt 5.7)

Answer (score 2):

use it like this

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/) -lshell32
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/) -lshell32

INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Include)
DEPENDPATH += $$quote(C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Include)
```

Make sure you run **qmake** after making changes to the .pro file

this could be auto generated by right clicking the project in the left panel
then select menu item **"Add Library"**

[image]

Then select **"External Library"**
[image]

Then select Static Library for windows and browse your path to select the path for the shell32.lib and include folder

[image]

Again make sure that you **run qmake** before you compile this project

this could be found in the projects menu .The same menu you found the  "Add Library" option

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio default install didn't include desktop apps:

[image: Click for Visual Studio installer option]